# Vue-router v4: Nested route not matching with parent route

Tags: vue.js, vue-router4

In this project I'm using Vue 3 (vite) and Vue-router v4 and trying to make routing work correctly.

I am trying to navigate to `/escape-rooms/my-escape-room` but the `<router-link>` object inside my menu does not get the class `.router-link-active`. In the main route `/escape-rooms` it does. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong because the documentation states that nested routes automatically 'activate' any parent links with this class.

I have this list of routes:

```
    const routes = [
        {path: '/', name: 'main', component: Home},
        {path: '/escape-rooms', name: 'escape-rooms', component: EscapeRooms},
        {path: '/escape-rooms/:urlName', name: 'escape-room-item', component: EscapeRooms, props: true},
        {path: '/contact', name: 'contact', component: Contact}      
   ]
```

This is de  part of my menu layout:

```
     <div class="menu">
        <div class="menuitem">
          <router-link to="/contact">
            contact
          </router-link>
        </div>
        <div class="menuitem">
          <router-link to="/escape-rooms">
            escape-rooms
          </router-link>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone stumbling on the same issue. follow this article: https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/master/active-rfcs/0028-router-active-link.md#unrelated-but-similiar-routes